# How to start multiprocessing process?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a code modified to add multiprocessing. My code now look like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Dates.csv', parse_dates=True)
df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df['dates']=df['dates'].dt.date

path="Testordner"
os.chdir(path)
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format("csv"))]
os.chdir("..")

def f(i):
    df2 = pd.read_csv("Testordner/"+i, parse_dates=True)
    df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['time'])
    df2['just_dates'] = df2['time'].dt.date
    dates2 = df2['just_dates']
    df['counts'+i]=df['dates'].isin(df2['just_dates']).astype(int) 

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
pool.map(f, result)
```

But nothing happens .. when I print my `df` it's like before. How can I start my multiprocessing ?
`df2['just_dates']` looks like:

```
     dates
0     2003-01-01
1     2003-01-02
2     2003-01-03
3     2003-01-04
4     2003-01-05
5     2003-01-06
6     2003-01-07
7     2003-01-08
8     2003-01-09
...
5287  2017-06-23
5288  2017-06-24
5289  2017-06-25
5290  2017-06-26
5291  2017-06-27
5292  2017-06-28
5293  2017-06-29
5294  2017-06-30
```

And `df2` for example:

```
0     2003-01-02
1     2015-10-31
2     2015-11-01
3     2015-11-01
4     2015-11-01
5     2015-11-01
6     2015-11-01
7     2015-11-01
8     2015-11-01
...
42    2015-11-03
43    2015-11-03
44    2015-11-04
45    2015-11-04
46    2015-11-04
```

This is a just_dates column for one example file.

Comment: The problem is that you are using `df` as a global variable to be used in `f()` but multiprocessing doesn't have shared memory. You should pass a copy of `df` to each function call and return the results.

Comment: I don't get it.. can you show me how it works?

Comment: I need a dummy df to try it out. Can you post a minimal df?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import pandas as pd


def f(i):
    df2 = pd.read_csv("Testordner/"+i, parse_dates=True)
    df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['time'])
    df2['just_dates'] = df2['time'].dt.date
    dates2 = df2['just_dates']
    return (i, df['dates'].isin(df2['just_dates']).astype(int))

with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
    results = p.map(f, result)
```

Comment: This is just an example. Your function `f()` now doesn't rely on mutable global variables. You still use `df` but you don't modify it. The function returns a tuple. `results` will contain all the tuples returned by `f()` called on each item in `result`. After that, you can use the data in `results` to finally edit `df`.

Comment: I tried this and still the same problem.. I really don't understand why

Comment: Can you see data in `results`?

Comment: I just become the "i"'s